# Azure Diagnostic Logs saved to another location

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I'm looking to create using Bicep, diagnostic settings on a firewall in one location and save to an Event Hub in another location. The two vnets are peered, but I am wondering if it is possibe based on this error message:

```
Resource '/subscriptions/123/resourceGroups/ukw-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls/ukw-fw' is in region 'ukwest' and resource '/subscriptions/123/resourcegroups/uks-rg/providers/microsoft.eventhub/namespaces/uks-evhns' is in region 'uksouth'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. It isn't possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/diagnostic-settings?tabs=portal#destination-limitations

*"The event hub namespace needs to be in the same region as the resource being monitored if the resource is regional."*

kind regards

Alistair

Comment: Perfect answer and many thanks Alistair. I did suspect that, but none of us know everything and I'm the first to say I know little about a lot!